# Facebook share text from app with facebook sdk

Tags: android, android-facebook

i am implementing sharing in my app. it just has to be text share.all apps worked fine with sharing text with intent but facebook doesn't allow to share text via intent. so i implemented its sdk and wrote down this code.

```
ShareContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                    .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                                    .setContentDescription(localThoughtDesc.get(finalI1))
                                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"))
                                    .build();

                            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

but i got output like this

[image]

i have gone through many tutorials. but most of them are deprecated. so if anyone can help me out it will be very nice.:)

Thank you :)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Try_me34 i want to share text to facebook. but i did't find a way to do it. if you can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i didn't get any way to post any thing on facebook so i tried another way to post text to facebook. Think it might helpful. By the way it is not actually sharing of text. I converted text into image file than i posted image through intent.
here's how i did it.

```
                 TextView textView=new TextView(getBaseContext());
                textView.setTag("textView");
                View view=innerLayout.findViewWithTag("textView");


                String SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/screenshots/";
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
                String path=SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

                final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

                view.draw(canvas);
                System.out.println(bitmap.getHeight()+" "+bitmap.getWidth());
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    final File sddir = new File(SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS);
                    if (!sddir.exists()) {
                        sddir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                    System.out.println(sddir.getPath().toString());
                    if (fos != null) {
                        if (!bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)) {
                            Log.d("abc", "Compress/Write failed");
                        }
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Title");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Extra Subject");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(path))); //optional//use this when you want to send an image
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "send"), REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook share doesn't support text. You can only share link and that will show the `<meta content ="...">` text from that page with your link in Facebook.

Comment: yeah you are right. but i have read in some tutorial or article said that it can be done via using facebook sdk.

Comment: I have implemented facebook sdk, tried a lot to share text but failed. If you get any solution please provide me also.

Comment: hey just check out my answer. I implemented it but its not actually text.